# Problemas com setInterval()

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){
  plusDivs(1);
}, 2500);
$(".mySlides").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(inter);
});
$(".mySlides").mouseleave(function(){
  var inter = setInterval(function(){
    plusDivs(1);
  }, 2500);
  console.log(inter);
});
```

No código acima mostrado, a variável `inter` é suposto ser um loop que para quando o cursor entre na `div`. Quando recarrego a página, o loop começa bem, quando passo o cursor por cima, para como deve ser, quanto removo o cursor da div, ele começa mas depois se passar de novo, ele não para e se retirar de novo, 2 loops começam ao mesmo tempo.

O slideshow foi baseado [neste aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)

Comment: É porque você está redeclarando a variável inter em `mouseleave`

Comment: E então como é que eu dou começo à variável `inter` de novo?

Comment: Tente dessa forma: `$(".mySlides").mouseleave(function(){
  inter = setInterval(function(){
    plusDivs(1);
  }, 2500);
  console.log(inter);
});` sem o *var*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Ou seja, removo o `var`... Sinto-me mal por ser um erro tão pequeno `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`, publique a resposta e eu aceitarei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo pois você está redeclarando a variável **inter**.

Quando você define uma variável fora do escopo da função `var inter = 0`, ela é global, podendo ser acessada através de qualquer outra função.

Quando você define uma variável dentro do escopo da função, ela passa a ser local, não podendo ser acessada fora da função.

```
// Global
var global = 0;

function myFunc() {
    // Local
    var local = 0;
}
```

O correto é dessa forma:

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){
  plusDivs(1);
}, 2500);

$(".mySlides").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(inter);
});

$(".mySlides").mouseleave(function(){
  inter = setInterval(function(){
    plusDivs(1);
  }, 2500);
  console.log(inter);
});
```

No seu caso, a melhor maneira de evitar esse erro, é utilizar função para sempre atribuir um valor a essa variável. Isso o ajudará ao manter o código a médio/longo prazo.

```js
var inter = setInterval(function(){
  //plusDivs(1);
  $("#log").text("Loop running...")
}, 2500);

$(".mySlides").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(inter);
  $("#log").text("Loop stoped.")
});

$(".mySlides").mouseleave(function(){
  inter = setInterval(function(){
    //plusDivs(1);
    $("#log").text("Loop running again...")
  }, 2500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mySlides">.mySlides</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variavel inter é global, não pode ser declarada novamente, apenas atribua o setinterval seria assim:

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){
  plusDivs(1);
}, 2500);
$(".mySlides").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(inter);
});
$(".mySlides").mouseleave(function(){
  inter = setInterval(function(){ // aqui não se define novamente a variavel inter
    plusDivs(1);
  }, 2500);
  console.log(inter);
});
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo funcional da correção nessa resposta?

Comment: Editado na resposta